# Trying to compare two integers in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Okay, I have been digging through Stackoverflow and other sites trying understand why this is not working.  I created a function to open a csv file.  The function opens the file once to count the number of rows then again to actually process the file.  What I am attempting to do is this. Once a file has been processed and the record counts match.  I will then load the data into a database.  The problem is that the record counts are not matching.  I checked both variables and they are both 'int', so I do not understand why '==' is not working for me.  Here is the function I created:

```
def mktdata_import(filedir):
    '''
    This function is used to import market data
    '''
    files = []
    files = filedir.glob('*.csv')

    for f in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(f,'*NASDAQ*'):
            num_rows = 0
            nasObj = []
            with open(f,mode='r') as nasData:
                nasIn = csv.DictReader(nasData, delimiter=',')
                recNum = sum(1 for _ in nasData)

            with open(f,mode='r') as nasData:
                nasIn = csv.DictReader(nasData, delimiter=',')
                for record in nasIn:
                    if (recNum - 1) != num_rows:
                        num_rows += 1
                        nasObj.append(record)
                    elif(recNum - 1) == num_rows:
                        print('Add records to database')
                    else:
                        print('All files have been processed')

            print('{} has this many records: {}'.format(f, num_rows))
            print(type(recNum))
            print(type(num_rows))

        else:
            print("Not a NASDAQ file!")
```

Comment: Try using `recNum = sum(1 for _ in nasIn)`. `nasData` includes the header row.

Comment: I gave that a go and my output now looks like this: marketData\NASDAQ\NASDAQ_20201023.csv has this many records: 1
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>

Comment: So, @Mike67 after trying your solution.  I tried using (recNum) == nasIn.line_num that appears to be working.  I am going to add in the section for the database upload and give it a try. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(moving comment to answer)

`nasData` includes all the rows in the file, including the header row. When converting the data to dictionaries with `DictReader`, only the data rows are processed so `len(nasData)` will always be one more than `len(nasIn)`

As the OP mentioned, iterating the elements did not work so using the line number was required to get the script working: `(recNum) == nasIn.line_num`